# how to change the adb target shell root directory with my pre-defined directory

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

i have my android device, whenever I am opening the adb client and giving the "adb shell" command, it is directly getting root directory.or if I want to push any file directly I am using adb push file.exe /data/ like this. but as per my requirement, nobody should able to access the root directory if they are trying to connect my device to PC. So I want to know the changes what i need to do so that before "adbd" launch, i will give a pre-defined directory, so that if anyone will push any file with that directory, only it will work or else it will fail.

Comment: Hi, it might come in handy if you first explain what you're trying to archieve. [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I want to protect the adb shell, so that only my given directory someone can push any file except this all other access should prevent means no access.
I can say adb shell should not work etc. Only adb push should work.